# Issue with Kdenlive rendering

Tags: kdenlive

I would love to start doing video editing. I've finished editing a video and I'm in the rendering process.

One issue I've had is that it renders for an hour and a half then crashes and said the speed may be affected.

Another issue I've had is once it's done rendering successfully, I play it back through VLC and it has cut off the first clip and last clip.

Any ideas of why this is happening??

Comment: Have you looked at the program logs?  You can probably track down what's happening by checking them.